# Piece And Pawn Only Massacre Games

Tags: problems, pawns, pieces, captures

What are the fastest possible games in which only all pieces and all pawns are captured? I did some searching myself.

**Pieces Only**

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 3/2/2019, Non-Unique Proof Game In 13.5 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. d3 d5 3. Qg4 Qg5 4. Qxc8+ Ke7 5. Qxb8 Qxc1+ 6. Ke2 Qxb1 7. Qxa8 Qxa1 8. Qxf8+ Kd7 9. Qxg8 Qxf1+ 10. Kd2 Qxg1 11. Qxh8 Qxh1 12. Qe8+ Kxe8 13. d4 Qe1+ 14. Kxe1
```

**Pawns Only**

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 3/2/2019, Non-Unique Proof Game In 16.0 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. f4 f5 3. g4 g5 4. h4 h5 5. d4 d5 6. c4 c5 7. b4 b5 8. a4 a5 9. bxa5  bxa4 10. cxd5 cxd4 11. exf5 exf4 12. gxh5 gxh4 13. Rxh4 Rxh5 14. Rxa4 Rxa5 15.  Rxd4 Rxd5 16. Rhxf4 Rhxf5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one for pieces only (12½ moves):

```
[FEN ""]

1. e3 e6 2. Na3 Na6 3. Bxa6 Bxa3 4. bxa3 bxa6 5. Qf3 Qf6 6. Qxa8 Qxa1 7. Qxc8+ Ke7 8. Qxg8 Qxc1+ 9. Ke2 Qxg1 10. Qxh8 Qxh1 11. h4 Qh3 12. Qf8+ Kxf8 13. gxh3
```

Also see [ħere](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/104183/70634)

Answer (score 7):

In the pawns only, you don't need to move so many pawns.  Getting the major pieces involved early seems to be fastest:

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Qh5 Qa5 3.Qxh7 Qxa2 4.Qxg7 Qxb2 5.Rxa7 Rxh2 6.Rxb7 Rxg2 7.Rxd7 Rxf2 8.Rxe7+ Kd8 9.Qxf7 Rxd2 10.Qf5 Qxc2 11.Qxc5 Qxe4+  *
```

I was unable to find a faster version of the piece only.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @DM, I managed to beat off another move by opening with a pawn capture and having one less check. Sorry mate!

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 3/3/2019, Non-Unique Proof Game In 10.0 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 d5 exd5 Qxd5 Qh5 Qxa2 Qxh7 Qxb2 Qxg7 Rxh2 Rxa7 Rxg2 Rxb7 Rxf2 Rxc7 Rxd2 Rxe7+ Kd8 Qxf7 Qxc2
```

Comment: Very nice: I prefer that the last move be 10. ... Qxc2 instead because it makes the diagram rotationally symmetric. A mirror-symmetric position (especially proof game) which in fact takes an odd number of moves to reach is called an oddity. So this rotationally symmetric position which surprisingly takes an even number of moves to reach could be called an evenity.